# Selenium - compound class names not permitted

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to get all elements with a certain class name:

```
theButtons = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("Icon Icon--medium Icon--reply");
```

However I get the error:

```
Compound class names not permitted
```

I understand that spaces are not allowed in the class name to get it, but then what should I do?

Thanks

Comment: try my answer and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try with xpath:

```
theButtons = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class,'Icon Icon--medium Icon--reply')]");
```

or

```
theButtons = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='Icon Icon--medium Icon--reply']");
```

Replace the quotes if I am wrong as I have less knowledge of Python